# Ionic View app Using Proxies

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I've successfully added a proxy to my ionic.config.json files which works when I do 'Ionic Serve' as well as with the Ionic Dev App. However, I'm having trouble loading it in Ionic View.

I saw recently (last week 12/4/17) they added HTTP plugin support with a CORS workaround for the Ionic View mobile app. However I can't seem to load any of my HTTP data from the proxy. Is Ionic View compatible with proxies? I know this issue if fairly new so there isn't much resources out there for it. Any help or lead in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support just got back to me - they have officially added plugins. Support docs are here in case anyone runs into the same issue...

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http